# Bind to a CheckBox and execute a command in a MVVM way

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013358/wpf-databinding-checkbox-ischecked), but in a more detailed situation. I am also trying to implement the solution using the Model View Viewmodel pattern.

In `MainView`, I have a button which calls a command (we'll call it `Execute`) stored in `MainViewModel`. I also want this command to be called when the left button of the mouse is clicked (actually, only on `Up`), but only when `MouseUpCheckBox` is checked.

When I had all the code in the view, I did static binding for `Execute`, but then used `ElementName` binding to the `Window` (named `w_window`) for `IsChecked` and checked the property value in the `MouseLeftButtonUpEvent` handler.

**XAML**

```
<Button Command="{x:Static local:MainView.Execute}">
    Execute
</Button>
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=w_window, Path=ExecuteOnMouseUp}">
    Execute on Mouse Up
</CheckBox>
```

**C#**

```
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(Execute, ExecuteExecuted));
    MyDesigner.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((o, eventArgs) =>
    {
        if (ExecuteOnMouseUp)
        {
            Execute.Execute(null, this);
        }
    }), true);
}

#region ExecuteOnMouseUp
/// <summary>
/// ExecuteOnMouseUp Dependency Property
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty ExecuteOnMouseUpProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ExecuteOnMouseUp", typeof(bool), typeof(MainView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((bool)false));

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the ExecuteOnMouseUp property. This dependency property 
/// indicates ....
/// </summary>
public bool ExecuteOnMouseUp
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(ExecuteOnMouseUpProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ExecuteOnMouseUpProperty, value); }
}
#endregion

#region Execute
/// <summary>
/// The Execute command ....
/// </summary>
public static RoutedUICommand Execute
    = new RoutedUICommand("Execute", "Execute", typeof(MainView));

private void ExecuteExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
#endregion
```

How can I port this code from my view into the viewmodel? Should I use an attached property? Is there a way to bind the checkbox value to a parameter in the `Command`, or maybe in the `CanExecute` handler? What's the idiomatic WPF/MVVM way of dealing with this kind of situation?

Comment: When I asked this question, I wasn't familiar with the idea of a CommandManager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188928.aspx). I don't know if this is built-in to WPF at all, but it seems relevant so I wanted to mention it here.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your example looks a bit too complicated for such a simple task as binding to a Button or a CheckBox.

You might have a look at the **ViewModel** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows how you can bind the IsChecked property to the ViewModel in a MVVM friendly way.

Answer (score 0):

Rachel provided a very good solution above, but in sake of comprehension I'm providing below details of different approach she mentioned (thanks to @Rachel again).

```
<...
 xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
...>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="ExecuteOnMouseUp">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Execute}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I tried both and found some differences in handling routed events. But in general, both methods work like a charm.