# One setting is determined by the second settings

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the same options in different WPF dialog. One option that depends on another. If I click on the first, I also want to check the second. Both options correspond to the private bool variable in different classes. What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Just to clarify - is the dependency from one dialog to another or are the dependent options in the same dialog. If B is dependent on A is it also true that A should be checked when B is checked ?

Comment: Is the dependency from one dialog to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that in WPF/XAML with Style.Triggers. For example the following code is an example on how to bind a textblock control's IsEnabled status based on the status of a checkbox (checked/unchecked)

```
<TextBlock Text="mytextblockText: ">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=myCheckbox}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=myCheckbox}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>                            
                </TextBlock>
```

For a checkbox being checked when another checkbox is checked, it looks like this (I guess)

```
<CheckBox>
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=myCheckbox}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=myCheckbox}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>                            
        </CheckBox>
```

*edit
can the properties in the classes be changed by something different than by those checkboxes? If yes, you could fire an event when the property is changed or directly manipulate the checkstate of the according box. Also, are the boxes dependent on each other? Or is just one dependent on the other (A <=> B or A => B)?

For manipulating the properties when one of the boxe's state is changed you could use the Checked/Unchecked events. Or use DependencyProperty as described in [Pat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116891/pat) answere over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013358/wpf-databinding-checkbox-ischecked)