# How to control some variable via C# code while it is referenced in xaml?

Tags: c#

```
                <RotateTransform3D CenterX="0" CenterY="0" CenterZ="0">
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0,1,0" Angle="35"/>
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
```

For above C# code, I want to set the value of `Angle` by my c# code (.cs) instead of xaml.
So I change it like below:

```
<AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0,1,0" Angle="AngleValue"/>
```

And in my cs code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    int AngleValue;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var t = new DispatcherTimer();
        // 1 second
        t.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        t.Tick += RotatePhoto;
        t.IsEnabled = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void RotatePhoto(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var current = this.myViewport3D.Children[0];
        //var translate = (current.Transform as Transform3DGroup).Children[0] as TranslateTransform3D;

        AngleValue++;
    }
```

But then VS told me that "`Input string was not in a correct format`". Could anyone tell me how to do it?

**More:**
I change my XAML code like: 
`<AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0,1,0" Angle="{Binding ElementName=Window1, Path=AngleValue}"/>` 
But the photo is static (won't rotate at all)...

Answer (score 0):

You write: `Angle="AngleValue"` 
`Angle` must a number

Answer (score 0):

XAML

```
<AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotation" Axis="0,1,0" />
```

Code behind

```
rotation.Angle++
```

NB: that's one way of doing it, but you should also have a look at the [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) that would allow you to write `Angle={Binding AngleValue}` in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `AngleValue` as a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx), and use databinding in your XAML to bind to the value.

For an example of creating the binding, [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1013430/93306).

```
<Window ... Name="MyWindow">
  <Grid>
    <AxisAngleRotation3D Axis="0,1,0" Angle="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=AngleValue}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Alternatively, you can give your AxisAngleRotation3D object an `x:Name` property and change your angle directly from the code-behind.